# Long to wide - Repeating columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've searched Tidyr and Dplyr Tags on this site and on Google for about two days and finally decided to post out of frustration....

I have the following data frame:

```
Name      Date   Sheets    Location    Weekday_vs_weekend    Cost
Jake    Aug 28    2          House            Weekday        .18
Jake    Aug 28    1          House            Weekday        .09
Kobe    Aug 28    3          Park             Weekend        .27
Kobe    Aug 28    2          Park             Weekend        .18
Jake    Aug 29    1          Library          Weekend        .09
Jordan  Aug 29    8          Library          Weekend        .72
Jordan  Aug 29    4          Library          Weekday        .36
```

I want the date variable to be turned into columns (I can do this with spread(), provide an aggregate sum of the total cost and sheets via aggregate(), use the aggregate sum of the sheets column PER date as the value to be used after the date's variable has been turned to columns, and then have the remaining variable be repeated for every date in the date column.

```
Name    Aug 28   Cost  Location    WkDay_WkEnd    Aug 29  Cost   Location    WkDay_WkEnd
Jake      3      27      House       Weekday         1    .09    Library       Weekday 
Kobe      5      45      Park        Weekday        NA     NA       NA           NA
Jordan    NA     NA       NA           NA           12    1.08   Library       Weekend
```

Comment: Could you tell us all what you want to do in a clear way? I am afraid I cannot follow you in the question. One more. Could I ask why you have NAs for Jordan and Kobe? I do not see logic behind it.

Comment: I have NA's for Jordan because Jordan didn't print anything on Aug. 28th and I have NA's for Kobe because he didn't print on Aug. 29th

Comment: Does your real data have more dates? If so, this'll get messy fast. It's better to make an easily copy-pastable example than to just show us a printout of your data, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible approach using the `data.table` package. Though I fail to see how are you going to use such a wide format.

The idea here is to sum the numeric column and then run `unique` on the non-numeric, then a simple join between the two

The main problem with using `tidyr` on such data set is that `spread` don't have a `fun.aggregate` attribute

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
indx <- sapply(df[names(df)[-(1:2)]], is.numeric)

DT1 <- dcast(setDT(df), 
       Name ~ Date, 
       value.var = names(df)[-(1:2)][indx],
       sum,
       fill = NA)

DT2 <- dcast(df, 
       Name ~ Date, 
       value.var = names(df)[-(1:2)][!indx],
       unique,
       fill = NA)

DT1[DT2, on = "Name"]
#      Name Sheets_sum_Aug 28 Sheets_sum_Aug 29 Cost_sum_Aug 28 Cost_sum_Aug 29 Location_unique_Aug 28 Location_unique_Aug 29
# 1:   Jake                 3                 1            0.27            0.09                  House                Library
# 2: Jordan                NA                12              NA            1.08                     NA                Library
# 3:   Kobe                 5                NA            0.45              NA                   Park                     NA
#    Weekday_vs_weekend_unique_Aug 28 Weekday_vs_weekend_unique_Aug 29
# 1:                          Weekday                          Weekend
# 2:                               NA                          Weekday
# 3:                          Weekend                               NA
```

Comment: I didn't realize the `on` option till now. Thanks for that.

Comment: @jazzurro yeah, it's a new feature in v 1.9.6+ (this is why added that upon `library`)